# Android: Is this good Idea to swap data in SQLite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have recycle view and arraylist which retrieved from SQLite database.

I use `ItemHelper` to swap item position in the arraylist.

The problem is item order in the database wouldn't change so that when app is closed and returned, the order will be recovered before.

From my research, swap data position in database is not good idea.

Can you share what would you do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If rows corresponding to items contain a significant amount of data then I think you should just add another column for the current position of each item and just update that in the database. While retrieving, you can `Order By` that column.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I decided for update the database.